# Truncating And Inserting on the same table at an instant

Tags: sql, db2, locking, deadlock

We use a DB2 database. Some datawarehouse tables are TRUNCATEd and reloaded every day. We run into deadlock issues when another process is running an INSERT statement against that same table.

Scenario

TRUNCATE is executed on a table.
At the same time another process INSERTS some data in the same table.(The process is based on a trigger and can start at any time )

is there a work around?
What we have thought so far is to prioritize the truncate and then go thruogh with the insert. Is there any way to iplement this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: My understanding is that you can only run into a deadlock in the above situation if both processes do some other work that requires additional locks. Is the TRUNCATE process doing just that or more?

Comment: the truncate is just truncating the records for the same table that the other process is trying to insert records into @data_henrik

Comment: It is important what the business rule is - which process has priority - it is very important and should be sequentialized anyway to get a reproduceable output

Comment: the insert statement has priority. A scenario where data is getting inserted and paralelly table is getting deleted should never happen. @MichaelTiefenbacher

Answer (score 1):

You should request a table lock before you execute the truncate.

If you do this you can't get a deadlock -- the table lock won't be granted before the insert finishes and once you have the lock another insert can't occur.

Update from comment:

You can use the **LOCK TABLE** command.  The details depend on your situation but you should be able too get away with SHARED mode.  This will allow reads but not inserts (this is the issue you are having I believe.)

It is possible this won't fix your problem.  That probably means your insert statement is to complicated -- maybe it is reading from a bunch of other tables or from a federated table.  If this is the case, re-architect your solution to include a staging table (first insert into the staging table .. slowly.. then insert into the target table from the staging table).

Comment: could you please let me know the process in detail. New to this database actually

Comment: The command is LOCK TABLE <tabname> in EXCLUSIVE MODE - details see http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000972.html?lang=en and do not forget to commit to release it again